# Filter dataset in reactive context in R Shiny with additional data processing steps after filter

Tags: r, shiny

I am having some trouble filtering a dataset within a reactive context (filter based on user specified input from dropdown menu) in a preliminary data processing step and then needing to do some additional data processing before creating the tables I want to display on my web page. I know that typically I would need to call my reactive dataframe within renderTable({}), but not quite sure how to do this with my current process.

Here is my ui code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-html-output table td {
                            width: 200px
                            }'))),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Survey Results 2021"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "question",
                  label = "Choose question to filter by", 
                  choices = list(
                    "1.\tHow knowledgeable do you feel you are about the general effects of climate change? Rate your personal knowledge below:" = "prsnl_knwldg_1",
                    "2.\tHow much do you think climate change will affect Pullman?" = "affect_pullman_2")
                  #selected = "No Filter"
      ),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "response",
                  label = "Select response to filter by",
                  choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl1"),
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl2")
      )
    ))
```

Here is my server code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  #Create example dataset
  prsnl_knwldg_1 <- c(rep("Highly knowledgeable", 5), rep("Very knowledgeable", 2), rep("Somewhat knowledgeable", 10), rep("Only slightly knowledgeable", 4), rep("Not knowledgeable",2))
  affect_pullman_2 <- c(rep("Don't know", 2), rep("In large ways that we humans cannot control", 5), rep("In large ways that we humans have the power to reduce", 1), rep("In small ways that will affect everyone", 4), rep("Moderately", 10), rep("Not at all", 1))
  seq <- seq(1,23,1)
  
  results <- data.frame(seq, prsnl_knwldg_1, affect_pullman_2)
  
  #Pivot dataset to create reactive filter
  results_long <- 
    results %>% 
    gather("Question", "Response", -seq)
  
  #reactive filter
  results_filt <- reactive({
    
    newdata <- results_long %>% filter(Question == input$question)
    
    newdata <- newdata %>% filter(Response == input$response)
    
    return(newdata)
    
  })
  
  #pivot dataset again for data summary code below
  results_wide <- 
    results_filt() %>% 
    spread(Question, Response)

  results_sum <- 
    lapply(names(results_wide), function(x){
      group_by_at(results_wide, x) %>%
        summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
        mutate(Pct_Num = round((Count/nrow(results_wide))*100),0) %>% 
        mutate(Pct = paste0(Pct_Num, "%")) %>% 
        mutate(Question = x) %>% 
        rename(Response = x) %>%
        as.data.frame()
    }
    )
  
  for (i in 1:length(results_sum)) {
    df <- results_sum[[i]]
    col <- unique(df[6])
    name <- pull(col)
    assign(name, as.data.frame(results_sum[[i]]))
  }
  
  prsnl_knwldg_1$Response = factor(prsnl_knwldg_1$Response, levels = c("Not knowledgeable", "Only slightly knowledgeable", "Somewhat knowledgeable", "Very knowledgeable", "Highly knowledgeable", "NA"))
  
  affect_pullman_2$Response = factor(affect_pullman_2$Response, levels = c("Not at all", "In small ways that will affect everyone", "Moderately", "In large ways that we humans cannot control", "In large ways that we humans have the power to reduce", "Don't know", "NA"))
  
  prsnl_knwldg_1 <- arrange(prsnl_knwldg_1, Response)
  affect_pullman_2 <- arrange(affect_pullman_2, Response)
  
  results_comb <- rbind(prsnl_knwldg_1, affect_pullman_2)
  
  #This piece of code makes the dropdown Question and Response filtering widgets dynamic (see ui)
  observeEvent(input$question,
               {
                 updateSelectizeInput(session, input = "response",
                                      choices = results_comb[results_comb$Question %in% input$question,
                                                             "Response", drop = TRUE])
               })
  
  #Tables ----
output$tbl1 <- renderTable({
  prsnl_knwldg_1_table <- 
    prsnl_knwldg_1 %>% 
    select(Response, Count, Pct)
}, caption = as.character(shiny::tags$b(style = "color: black", "1. How knowledgeable do you feel you are about the general effects of climate change?")), caption.placement = "top"
)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to select a data frame variable (column) using the environmental variable `input$question` within `filter()` - learned from chapter 12 of [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html)

```
    results_filt <- 
      results %>% 
      filter(.data[[input$question]] == input$response)
```

The following code worked for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

#Create example dataset
prsnl_knwldg_1 <- c(rep("Highly knowledgeable", 5), rep("Very knowledgeable", 2), rep("Somewhat knowledgeable", 10), rep("Only slightly knowledgeable", 4), rep("Not knowledgeable",2))
affect_pullman_2 <- c(rep("Don't know", 2), rep("In large ways that we humans cannot control", 5), rep("In large ways that we humans have the power to reduce", 1), rep("In small ways that will affect everyone", 4), rep("Moderately", 10), rep("Not at all", 1))
seq <- seq(1,23,1)
results <- data.frame(seq, prsnl_knwldg_1, affect_pullman_2)

# prepare choices for selectInput
prsnl_knwldg_1_levels <- c("Not knowledgeable", "Only slightly knowledgeable", "Somewhat knowledgeable", "Very knowledgeable", "Highly knowledgeable", "NA")
affect_pullman_2_levels <- c("Not at all", "In small ways that will affect everyone", "Moderately", "In large ways that we humans cannot control", "In large ways that we humans have the power to reduce", "Don't know", "NA")


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-html-output table td {
                            width: 200px
                            }'))),
    
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Survey Results 2021"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "question",
                  label = "Choose question to filter by", 
                  choices = list(
                    "1.\tHow knowledgeable do you feel you are about the general effects of climate change? Rate your personal knowledge below:" = "prsnl_knwldg_1",
                    "2.\tHow much do you think climate change will affect Pullman?" = "affect_pullman_2")
                  #selected = "No Filter"
      ),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "response",
                  label = "Select response to filter by",
                  choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl1"),
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl2")
    )
  ))


server <- function(input, output, session) ({
  
  #This piece of code makes the dropdown Question and Response filtering widgets dynamic (see ui)
  observeEvent(input$question,
               {
                 updateSelectizeInput(session, input = "response",
                                      choices = switch(input$question,  "prsnl_knwldg_1" = prsnl_knwldg_1_levels, "affect_pullman_2" = affect_pullman_2_levels))
               })
  
  #Tables ----
  output$tbl1 <- renderTable({
    
    results_filt <- 
      results %>% 
      filter(.data[[input$question]] == input$response)
    
    tbl1 <- results_filt %>% 
      select(prsnl_knwldg_1) %>% 
      group_by(prsnl_knwldg_1) %>% 
      summarise (
        Count = n()
      ) %>% 
      mutate(Pct_Num = round((Count/nrow(results_filt))*100),0) %>% 
      mutate(Pct = paste0(Pct_Num, "%")) %>%
      rename(Response = prsnl_knwldg_1) %>% 
      select(Response, Count, Pct)
    
   }, caption = as.character(shiny::tags$b(style = "color: black", "1. How knowledgeable do you feel you are about the general effects of climate change? Rate your personal knowledge below:")), caption.placement = "top"
  )
  
  output$tbl2 <- renderTable({
    
    results_filt <- 
      results %>% 
      filter(.data[[input$question]] == input$response)
    
    tbl2 <- results_filt %>% 
      select(affect_pullman_2) %>% 
      group_by(affect_pullman_2) %>% 
      summarise (
        Count = n()
      ) %>% 
      mutate(Pct_Num = round((Count/nrow(results_filt))*100),0) %>% 
      mutate(Pct = paste0(Pct_Num, "%")) %>%
      rename(Response = affect_pullman_2) %>% 
      select(Response, Count, Pct)
    
  }, caption = as.character(shiny::tags$b(style = "color: black", "2. How much do you think climate change will affect Pullman?")), caption.placement = "top"
  )
  
})
    

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how you want to process things, but here is a starting point that you can modify:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

#Create example dataset
prsnl_knwldg_1 <- c(rep("Highly knowledgeable", 5), rep("Very knowledgeable", 2), rep("Somewhat knowledgeable", 10), rep("Only slightly knowledgeable", 4), rep("Not knowledgeable",2))
affect_pullman_2 <- c(rep("Don't know", 2), rep("In large ways that we humans cannot control", 5), rep("In large ways that we humans have the power to reduce", 1), rep("In small ways that will affect everyone", 4), rep("Moderately", 10), rep("Not at all", 1))
seq <- seq(1,23,1)
results <- data.frame(seq, prsnl_knwldg_1, affect_pullman_2)
results_long <- 
    results %>% 
    gather("Question", "Response", -seq)

# prepare choices for selectInput
prsnl_knwldg_1_levels <- c("Not knowledgeable", "Only slightly knowledgeable", "Somewhat knowledgeable", "Very knowledgeable", "Highly knowledgeable", "NA")
affect_pullman_2_levels <- c("Not at all", "In small ways that will affect everyone", "Moderately", "In large ways that we humans cannot control", "In large ways that we humans have the power to reduce", "Don't know", "NA")


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-html-output table td {
                            width: 200px
                            }'))),
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Survey Results 2021"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "question",
                        label = "Choose question to filter by", 
                        choices = list(
                            "1.\tHow knowledgeable do you feel you are about the general effects of climate change? Rate your personal knowledge below:" = "prsnl_knwldg_1",
                            "2.\tHow much do you think climate change will affect Pullman?" = "affect_pullman_2")
                        #selected = "No Filter"
            ),
            
            selectInput(inputId = "response",
                        label = "Select response to filter by",
                        choices = NULL)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput(outputId = "tbl1"),
            tableOutput(outputId = "tbl2")
        )
    ))


server <- function(input, output, session) ({
    
    #This piece of code makes the dropdown Question and Response filtering widgets dynamic (see ui)
    observeEvent(input$question,
                 {
                    updateSelectizeInput(session, input = "response",
                                         choices = switch(input$question,  "prsnl_knwldg_1" = prsnl_knwldg_1_levels, "affect_pullman_2" = affect_pullman_2_levels))
                 })
    
    
    #reactive filter
    results_filt <- reactive({
        results_long %>%
            filter(Question == input$question,
                   Response == input$response)
    })

    # further processing:
    results_display <- reactive({
        results_wide <- results_filt() %>% 
            spread(Question, Response)
        
        results_sum <-
            lapply(names(results_wide), function(x){
                group_by_at(results_wide, x) %>%
                    summarise(Count = n()) %>%
                    mutate(Pct_Num = round((Count/nrow(results_wide))*100),0) %>%
                    mutate(Pct = paste0(Pct_Num, "%")) %>%
                    mutate(Question = x) %>%
                    rename(Response = x) %>%
                    as.data.frame()
            }
            )
        
        results_sum
    })
    

    #Tables ----
    output$tbl1 <- renderTable({
        results_display()
    }, caption = as.character(shiny::tags$b(style = "color: black", "1. How knowledgeable do you feel you are about the general effects of climate change?")), caption.placement = "top"
    )
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You'll notice that I filter the data in a `reactive()`, and then process a second time in another `reactive()` that gets called by the `renderTable()`.  I did this because it mimics the flow I think you were trying to make.  But actually, unless you reuse these reactives elsewhere, there is no benefit to splitting like this.  You could simply compute everything inside the `renderTable()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for lack of clarity about my desired final outcome and I see now my original approach was misleading. Ultimately, I want a separate table for each column (prsnl_knwldg_1 and affect_pullman_2) in the results data frame that shows count and pct of each response option. The filters will choose a column and response option to filter by, which in turn will filter results for all my tables. Something I'm struggling with is selecting a column in a reactive format (e.g., `results %>% filter(input$question == input$response` doesn't seem to work). Does that provide more clarity?

Comment: I already have `filter(Question == input$question, Response == input$response)` in my answer.  Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: You might want to read Chapter 12 of [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html).  The whole book is both useful and freely available online. But in particular, it shows you how to do things like `data() %>% filter(.data[[input$var]] > input$min)` which you might find helpful.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the Mastering Shiny resource. The option of using data-masking functions did the trick for me, as you suggested. I also ended up putting the reactive features within `renderTable()`. I'll post what worked for me below. Thanks again for your help